# Vue 3 "sameAs(*locator)" @vuelidate/core rarely not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate, password-confirmation

I'm working in a front-end app with Vue 3, @vuelidate/core, @vuelidate/validators and Bulma Framework.

However I have a month and a few weeks trying to validate a "confirmPassword" field, and I've tried by 3 different ways:

1. By using sameAs() function from @vuelidate/validators in a utils.js file. Like This

```
import { helpers, sameAs } from '@vuelidate/validators'
    
const sameAsH = (impresion, parametro) => {
    let compare  =  helpers.withMessage(
        impresion + " no coinciden",
        sameAs(parametro)
    );

    return compare;
}
```

"impresion" is a variable for print in a `<p>` label and "parametro" comes from vue-model from sign up component

I've tried sending to "parametro" a string with "usuario.pwd" or "this.usuario.pwd" as a *locator instead a function, like the docs of sameAs()/vuelidate says, but it compares with the pure string and not with the value, as if my password was "usuario.pwd" or "this.usuario.pwd" literally, if I write these strings then the validation return value is true, but it doesn't match with my usuario.pwd value.

2. By using "helpers.withAsync" in utils.js

```
import { helpers } from '@vuelidate/validators'
import config from './Config'

const sameAsH = (impresion, parametro) => {
    let compare  =  helpers.withMessage(
        impresion + " no coinciden",
        helpers.withAsync(async (value)=>{
            let retorno;
            // let funcCompare = parametro
            // let comp = await funcCompare();
            // if(await value == comp){
            if(await value == parametro){
                retorno = true;
            }
            else{
                retorno = false;
            }

            console.log("PRINT 1: "+value+"\nPRINT 2: "+parametro+"\nPRINT 3: "+retorno)

            return retorno;
        })
    );
    return compare;
}
```

When I'm interacting with password and confirmPassword fields, the "console.log" statement print this:

[image]

It repeats because the const/function is executed when a character is tiped in the input field. (vuelidate makes this)

PRINT 1: Value of ConfirmPassword input field.

PRINT 2: "Value" of this.usuario.pwd. It comes from vue model in SignUp.vue component. I'm trying to get the value of the vue-model from a function. (I will show you forward). This should be "12345678"

PRINT 3: The vuelidation return value, always false until my passwords match or not.

Look at the commented lines, I was just thinking: "What if I execute 'parametro' value like a function?". But if I uncomment that, the code does not execute the "console.log" statement and the vuelidation return value still being false.

3. Using "helpers.withParams" in utils.js
   At this point I was going crazy, and I'm not sure how this works, but there is something I'm really sure... Vuelidation return value still being false until password match or not :C.

```
const sameAsH = (impresion, parametro) => {
    let compare  =  helpers.withMessage(
        impresion + " no coinciden",
        helpers.withParams({ type: 'sameAs', eq: parametro }, function(value, parentVm){
            return value === ref(parametro, this, parentVm)
        })
    );

    return compare;
}
```

This is the "parametro" content:

```
function(){
    return this.usuario.pwd;
}
```

The "parametro" parameter value is always the same.

Then I export this const (sameAsH/"sameAs helper") for using it at SingUp.vue.

`import { requiredH, availableH, emailH, minLengthH,`  here: `sameAsH } from '../utils'`

My vue code in SignUp.vue looks like this:

```
export default {
    name: "login",
    data: ()=>
    ({
        usuario: {
            id: 0,
            username: '',
            pwd: '',
            pwd2: '',
            dui: '',
            nit: '',
            nombres: '',
            apellidos: '',
            code: 0,
            mail: '',
            confirm: 0,
        },
        modal: {
            active: ""
        },
        errors: {
            session: null
        }
    }),
    setup: () => ({ v$: useVuelidate()}),
    validations: () => ({
            usuario: {
                nombres: { requiredH },
                apellidos: { requiredH },
                username: {
                    requiredH,
                    availableUser: availableH("usuario","User", "usuario", axios),
                    minLength: minLengthH("El usuario", 6)
                },
                mail: {
                    requiredH,
                    emailH,
                    availableMail: availableH("email", "Email", "correo electrónico", axios)
                },
                pwd: { requiredH, minLength: minLengthH("La contraseña", 8) },
                dui: { requiredH },
                nit: { requiredH },
                pwd2: { sameAsPassword: sameAsH( "Las contraseñas", function(){
                    return this.usuario.pwd;
                }) }
            }
    })
}
```

Please take special atention at usuario.pwd2 validation, here is when I use sameAsH const from utils.js.

If you think util.js is the problem, trust me, I've tried before doing all in the SignUp.vue component, passing all validators to utils.js and then export these by a const was a "possible solution" and a "make things with more order" attemp.

If you know a way to validate password confirmation with @vuelidate/core and @vuelidate/validators, or if you know what I'm doing wrong, please tell me. Feel free to make your questions... Please help, I'm fed up with this.

And this is the behavior always (until my passwords match or not):

[image]
:C

Comment: You can try with         pwd2: { required: helpers.withMessage('Enter Confirm Password', required), sameAsPassword: helpers.withMessage('Password should match', sameAs(this.usuario. pwd)) }, hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was this arrow function on "vallidations: ()=>({ })" when you have ()=>({}) instead ()=>{} you're passing a literal object, and the content can't be changed. So you have to remove the parenthesis before the "{}" and it will work. Thank You